# React is redirecting after refresh using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux

I am building simple authentication application using MERN + Redux in which after user successfully logs in is redirected to Home Page in which I dispatch an action which returns cookie ( login successful is equal to cookie = true, and vice versa )

This is code in Home Page

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const cookie_info = useSelector( state => state.is_user_logged_in );
const { cookie, loading } = cookie_info;
React.useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(get_cookie_action());
},[]);

return (
    <>
        {
            loading 
            ?
            <h1>LOADING</h1>
            :
            (
                cookie
                ?
                (
                   <div>
                        <Navbar/>
                   </div>
                )
                :
                <Redirect to="/login"/>
            )
        }
    </>
);
```

The problem is after user logs in everything works but after I refresh home page I am redirected to login page again, It seams that React does not wait for redux state change of cookie from false to true and immediately 'fires'

```
   <Redirect to="/login"/>
```

part of code. My initial state of cookie in reducers is false.

Comment: It seems like you need to persist your redux store so that on refresh, it doesn't restore back to the initial state. Read more about [redux persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist).

Comment: Why do you store cookie in redux store ? Better you store it as a browser cookie in which it will persist even if your browser closed (until cookie expires) ?

Comment: @K.vindi I am storing cookie inside browser cookie and it is httpOnly so I dispatch an action to NodeJs backend in which I return true/false whether the cookie is valid